# How can you edit Build Parameters in Jenkins Workflow?

Tags: groovy, jenkins, parameters, workflow

I know that you can access build parameters directly in the Jenkins Workflow. I have a parameter called BRANCH_REVISION which I need to update so that a call to the xml api will show the new value instead of the original value. This is something I was doing in a non-workflow script using the following groovy snippet:

```
def currentParamActions = build.getAction(ParametersAction.class)
def currentParams = currentParamActions.getParameters()

currentParams.each() {
    if ( it.name.equals("BRANCH_REVISION") ) {
        newParams.add( new StringParameterValue("BRANCH_REVISION", newRevision ) )
    }
    else {
        newParams.add( it )
    }
}

build.actions.remove(currentParamActions)
new_param_actions = currentParamActions.createUpdated(newParams)
build.actions.add(new_param_actions)
```

However, it appears that this does not work in Workflow since the build object is not accessible. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See *<Workflow job configuration> → **Workflow** →* ☑ *Snippet Generator → **Global variables** → Variable: currentBuild*:

> The `currentBuild` variable may be used to refer to the currently running build. It is an object similar to that documented for the return value of the `build` step.

Use `currentBuild.build()` instead of `build` in the code in your question according to [`org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/d3f66c6f04d1d979957f02819b19291e2c35e276/support/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.java) which is the type of `currentBuild`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I looked at the currentBuild variable, but I have been unable to figure out how to use it to overwrite the value of an existing parameter. Do you have any further insight into this?

Comment: @Josh I suggest to try replacing `build` in the code in your question with `currentBuild`.

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, currentBuild does not have most of the methods that are available to build, including any access to setting actions.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to update your answer. 

Your solution worked, it successfully updated the parameters, but the next step in the code when I try to start a job using the node() command, a 'java.io.NotSerializableException: hudson.model.ParametersAction' error bubbles up and kills the script. I tried putting the parameter changing code into a @NonCPS function, but this did not fix the issue unfortunately.

Comment: @Josh I think „_the next step in the code_“ deserves an own question. If you find this answer useful, see [Help Center > Answering](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. Thank you for your time and reasearch, I owe you a pint for sure!